# Python Binary number to decimal simple convertor

Tags: python, for-loop, binary, decimal

```
userinput=(input ("Please Enter Your Binary Number"))


lengh=len (userinput)

x=lengh-1
num=(2**x)


char2=-lengh

for i in range(lengh)

int(userinput[char2])*num

x=x-1
char2=char2+1
```

Basically, I am trying to make a Binary to decimal converter for my GCSE using only simple commands. How should I arrange the for loop so that it runs until all the numbers are converted. Furthermore, how can I print out the addition of all the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I'll walk through a simple way to do this:

```
s = '101101101'
```

Reverse the string, so we can operate right-to-left. This can be done with slicing `s[::-1]`. Then we can use `enumerate` to effectively get the power based on the index.

```
total = 0
for index, value in enumerate(s[::-1]):
    total += int(value) * 2**index

>>> total
365
```

So walking through the first few iterations of the for loop

```
total += 1 * 2**0
total += 0 * 2**1
total += 1 * 2**2
total += 1 * 2**3
... etc
```